# How to prove that the massive gauge fields transform in the fundamental representation of the gauge group of unbroken generators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

In Chapter 84 (page 528) of Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory, he wrote

> Recall from section $32$ that a generator $T^a$ is spontaneously broken if $(T^a_{\scriptscriptstyle{\text{R}}})_{ij} v_j \ne 0$.  From eq.$(84.11)$, we see that gauge fields correponding to broken generators get a mass, while those corresponding to unbroken generators do not. The unbroken generators (if any) form a gauge group with massless gauge fields.  **The massive gauge fields (and all other fields) form representations of this unbroken group.**
>
> Let us work out some simple examples.
>
> Consider the gauge group $SU(N)$, with a complex scalar field $\varphi$ in the fundamental representation.  We can make a global $SU(N)$ transformation to bring the VEV entirely into the last component, and furthermore make it real.  Any generator ${(T^a)_i}^j$ that does not have a nonzero entry in the last column will remain unbroken.  These generators form an unbroken $SU(N-1)$ gauge group.  There are three classes of broken generators:  those with ${(T^a)_i}^N =\frac{1}{2}$ for $i \ne N$ (there are $N-1$ of these); those with ${(T^a)_i}^N = -\frac{1}{2}i$ for $i\ne N$ (there are also $N-1$ of these), and finally the single generator $T^{N^2-1}=[2N(N-1)]^{-1/2} \text{diag}(1,\cdots,1,-(N-1))$.  The gauge fields corresponding to the generators in the first two classes get a mass $M=\frac{1}{2}gv$; **we can group them into a complex vector field that transforms in the fundamental representation of the unbroken $SU(N-1)$ subgroup.**  The gauge field corresponding to $T^{N^2-1}$ gets a mass $M=[(N-1)/2N]^{1/2}gv$; **it is a singlet of $SU(N-1)$.**

where I've marked as **bold** the sentences I can't understand.

How to prove that the massive gauge fields transform in the fundamental representation of the gauge group of unbroken generators?

**Edit:**

In order to avoid ambiguity, I've modified the question from 'how to understand' to 'how to prove'.

Comment: You understand what each of those terms mean individually, right?

Comment: They constitute a complex *N*-1 dimensional vector, transforming in the obvious way under SU(N-1), analogous to the *N* dimensional vector $\varphi$ transforming under SU(N). Do you understand what that means?